# ¿Es posible acceder a la configuracion de notificaciones con React Native? - IOS

Tags: react-native

Quiero poder acceder al panel de notificaciones y activar o desactivarla desde una app React

Comment: Si puedes abrir la configuración de las notificaciones pero el usuario decide si activa o no, no se puede automáticamente en iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Actualmente la única posibilidad, es abrir la configuración nativa de la siguiente forma:

```
import { openSettings } from 'react-native-permissions';
openSettings();
```

Documentación oficial para abrir la configuración nativa del dispositivo.

[OpenSettings React Native Permissions](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions#opensettings)

Revisá si podes redireccionarlo directo a las push.